# How can I add an Ad banner bigger than the one of default in Xcode?

Tags: iphone, xcode, swift, ads

I would like to add an Ad banner to my app but I would like to use not the usual one at the bottom or at the top of the screen, rather this one, that I've seen in several apps:

[image]

Is there a way to change Ad banner?

Answer (score 1):

With mobile ads there are two key ad types you can use. The ones at the bottom or top of the screen are known as banners where as the one you posted is known as an interstitial. Admob, by Google, is a very nice option for incorporating ads. However, do your research and see what ad network works best for you. The actual implementation of the code and advertisement into Xcode varies from each network’s SDK.